# Python file download with encrypted links

Tags: python, download, python-requests, get, wget

The website has a download button, when i hover over it, it is something like this (this is real url with only the actual website changed.)

```
https://whatthehell.com/download.php?file=Tzo4OiJzdGRDbGFzcyI6NDp7czoyOiJpcCI7czoxNToiMjIwLjI1NS4xOTguMjE2IjtzOjg6ImZpbGVOYW1lIjtzOjI2OiJ0aGVtZXMvMTM5MDQxX3ZlZW4yMTRuLnppcCI7czo5OiJyZXR1cm5VcmwiO3M6NzU6Imh0dHBzOi8vdmVzdGF0aGVtZXMuY29tL3ZlZW4tdjItMS00LW1pbmltYWwtbGlnaHR3ZWlnaHQtYmxvZy1mb3Itd29yZHByZXNzLyI7czo4OiJzZWN1cml0eSI7czo0MDoiNDhiMTc0NmIzNjEzZTIyYzJhMmFkNDcyMmZiMjE1ZjlhODRmY2RkOCI7fQ==
```

from python when i read the page, no such link is found, the javascript found on the page has the actual file download url but it doesnt work even if you paste the url in actual browser. the function from view source is like this.

```
<script type="ac07064234e8f34f59a0999f-text/javascript">
var DownloadFile = "something/something.zip";
var defaultDownloadUrl = "https://whatthehell.com/something/something.zip"; (this url does not work even if paste from browser)
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
IF STATMENT IS HERE 
xhttp.open("GET", "/generateDownloadUrl.php?returnUrl=" + window.location.href +"&fileName=" + DownloadFile, true);
```

Can i scrape the encrypted download link or is there any python code to download from the above url?
Any help appreciated...

Comment: i think is where beautifulsoup fails. The link that gets generated for download is being generated on hover event and this is something you cant do with beautifulsoup.

Comment: Have you looked at Selenium?

Comment: okay thanks, i will look into that...

Comment: Selenium is definitely going to work, although speed is nothing compared to python scripts, because this is going to be like me clicking on the button, just that the actions is replace by the program. But still, this is better than nothing at all. Thanks, I will proceed to close.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Selenium is the way to go. From reading documentation and some videos on yt, I am sure it's going to work. Speed wise will be a factor if I am going to scrape hundreds or thousands of pages.